# PowerShell Active Directory ACL script

Tags: powershell, server, dns, acl, privileges

I got stucked when creating my script. It checks whether the user exists, and if they don't have home directory, it should create one. However I need help with an ACL section.

My goal is that the principal of the newly created folder will be the user. And I also like to assign FileSystemAccessRule to the user, so they will have provided desired privileges.

I am enclosing code and output.

```
$user = Read-Host "user's domain login"
if($user -ne $Null){
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -like $user }
    $sac = $user.SamAccountName
}

$domain = Get-ADDomain
$path = "C:\vcgdysrnas03\users\$user"

If(!(Test-Path $path)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path -ea Stop
}

Set-ADUser -Identity $sac -HomeDirectory $path -HomeDrive C -ea Stop


$acl = $null
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
$acl.SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]"$user")


$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$domain\$sac", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")

$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl | fl
```

One error relates to setting owner of folder,

```
$acl.SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]"$user")
```

Second is referring to to the user and domain (I've tried several combinations but with no avail).

```
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$domain\$sac", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
```

[image: image output with two errors]

Comment: What happens if instead of passing `$user` to `$acl.SetOwner()`, you pass `$sac`?

Comment: Also, rather than pasting an image of your error, copy the text and insert it (between lines of triple backticks) into the question directly. The picture may be difficult to see on anything but the largest screens.

Comment: problem solved, replacing $user with $sac is a great solution!